# $\ell$-adic represetations of local fields not from geometry

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a local field (an intermediate field between $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$) and $\ell$ be another prime.

According to [this book](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Efontaine/galoisrep.pdf) (Theorem 1.24-Theorem1.26), we know

> If $K/\mathbb Q_p$ is finite, then all $\ell$-adic representations are all potentially semi-stable.

> Any $\ell$-adic representations coming from algebraic geometry are all potentially semi-stable.

> If the residue field of $K$ is algebraically closed, all potentially semi-stable $\ell$-adic representations come from algebraic geometry.

So my first question is: do all $\ell$-adic representations come from algebraic geometry?

It seems not. In the finite case, the first two hold, but the third fails. So there could be that some representations are not obtained by taking etale cohomology. In the algebraically closed case, the last two holds, but first fails. So there possibly $\ell$-adic representations are not potentially semi-stable.

Are there any examples that do not come from geometry (in both finite and algebraically closed cases)? Also is there a way to describe these representation not from algebraic geometry?

Comment: Theorem $1.26$ says that if the residue field $k$ is algebraically closed then any potentially semistable
$\ell$-adic representation of the absolute Galois group $G_K$ comes from (algebraic) geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t understand what a representation of $\overline{K}$ coming from algebraic geometry can be (since the Galois group of $\overline{K}$ is trivial), but for any finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, it’s easy to find a representation that cannot come from algebraic geometry.

Consider the $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-line with Galois action given by $G_K \rightarrow G_k =\hat{\mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow 1+\ell \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \subset \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}^{\times}$, where $1$ is mapped to any non-algebraic number. This representation is not pure, so by Theorem 1.21 (and discussion above) does not come from algebraic geometry.

**Edit**: As clarified in the comment, when $K$ has algebraically closed residue field, consider the case where $K$ is the completion of the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Fix a sequence $(q_n)$ with $q_0=p$, $q_{n+1}^l=q_n$, and let $u: G_K \rightarrow T_{\ell}\mathbb{G}_m \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \rightarrow 1+\ell\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}\subset \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}^{\times}$ given by $u(s)=(s(q_n)/q_n)_{n \geq 1}$.

Then $u$ defines a Galois $\ell$-adic character of $K$ which is *not* potentially semi-stable, thus cannot come from geometry.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: but that group is trivial!

Comment: So $G_K$ is trivial if $K$ is a local field with algebraically closed residue field $k$, you mean? Sorry, I am just confused. Then Theorem $1.26$ makes no sense. The OP did not cite the theorem correctly, perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the residue field si algebraically clsoed.